# python version of a php curl request

Tags: python, php

i want to test an API in python but im a beginner with api's in python and i don't know PHP at all and example how to get a auth key is in php. Everything i found didn't work for me there was an errors or 401 request. So i want to ask i any one can help me with translate this into python request ?

```
<?php

function getAccessToken(): String
{
    $authUrl = "https://allegro.pl.allegrosandbox.pl/auth/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials";
    $clientId = "...";
    $clientSecret = "...";

    $ch = curl_init($authUrl);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, $clientId);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, $clientSecret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $tokenResult = curl_exec($ch);
    $resultCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($tokenResult === false || $resultCode !== 200) {
        exit ("Something went wrong");
    }

    $tokenObject = json_decode($tokenResult);

    return $tokenObject->access_token;
}

function main()
{
    echo "access_token = ", getAccessToken();
}

main();
```

Comment: Have you tried translating it into Python? If you try, people can address the particular problems with your translation; and also better understand what level of explanation you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is easy to learn and exciting to use. Here is the translation:

```
import requests

def getAccessToken():
    authUrl = "https://allegro.pl.allegrosandbox.pl/auth/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials"
    clientId = "..."
    clientSecret = "..."

    tokenResult = requests.post(authUrl, auth=(clientId, clientSecret))
    resultCode = tokenResult.status_code
  

    if resultCode != 200:
        print("something went wrong")
        exit (1)

    tokenObject = tokenResult.json()

    return tokenObject['access_token']

def main():
    print("access_token = {}".format(getAccessToken()))

main()
```